# mssql-server suddenly crashes on startup

Tags: server, mssql

I've recently noticed that my MSSQL server doesn't start anymore. It just throws the error:

```
sqlservr: Unable to read instance id from /var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id: File: pal.cpp:438 [Status: 0xC0000034 Object name not found errno = 0x2(2) No such file or directory]
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: PAL initialization failed. Error: 101
```

I've already tried to run the setup again (which also throws this error when ran), and even installed it completely new, with no effect.
I'm running Ubuntu server 22.04 which worked a week ago (I know It's not officially supported but what can I do?)
Also, I've found no one with a similar problem on the internet.
The server ran for about a year with no problems whatsoever, and I've changed nothing, so I'm quite confused how and why it suddenly broke.

I would really appreciate any help with this.

Regards,
Fischchen

Comment: "I'm running Ubuntu server 22.04 which worked a week ago (I know It's not officially supported but what can I do?)" sorry? How is 22.04 not supported? Is that a typo?

Comment: What are the file and directory permissions for `/var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id`? Is there anything in `/var/opt/mssql/log` that points more specifically to the problem? 

Comment: @Rinzwind according to Microsofts website is mssql-server only compatible with 20.04